# Bash script bulk extract content from html and separate to each domain

Tags: bash, curl

I have a bulk of 2500 domains which I have to check daily and see if there is any content updated. Each page has in its source a stamp

```
timeSincePublish:123412412
```

which can be tracked and I need to check this stamp for all domains and extract it for each one aside.

Right now I have this command :

```
cat url.txt | xargs -n 1 curl -L0 | grep -oP '"timeSincePublish":(\d+)' -
```

Which analyze all domains from `url.txt` and extracts the stamp but I can save just the stamps and I would like to know how I can output the domain and timestamp in a `csv` or something like that.

So I would have:

```
domain.com - timesincepublished: 133213124
eweqwe.com - timesincepublished: 312316
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
while read -r domain; do
    timestamp=$(curl -L0 "$domain" | grep -op "timeSincePublish:\k\d+")
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$domain" "$timestamp"
done < url.txt > output.file
```

Comment: And this should be in a .sh file? and run as a bash script?

Comment: You could just run that on the command line as-is. You could add it in a function to your .bashrc. You could put it in a file to run as a bash script. The choice is yours.

Comment: Unfortunately it just outputs the domain name. http://imgur.com/JfG63Sb

Comment: Fixed it - there was a typo.